# Message during big file load in R

Tags: r

Is there any ways to print message during big file load or time consuming processing and calculations in R? if it will be with some countdown timer it will be also great. 
Thank's for suggestions.

Comment: What kind of calculations? What size vectors are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the functions `txtProgressBar`, `winProgressBar` (windows only), and `tkProgressBar` (tcltk package).  These can be used to show a progress bar to indicate how far along in a long process you are.  Some of them have room for a label that you could use to give a more specific message.

There are a few functions that will use these (the `plyr` package), otherwise you need to code the updates yourself, but this is pretty simple if you are using a loop or one of the `*apply` functions.

Comment: I'm guessing these won't help the OP, who's more likely doing `read.csv(big_honking_file.csv)` . He'll have to write a loop which loads N lines per cycle w/ some `sprintf('finished next %d lines',1000*iloopcount)`